# Ionic Firebase CRUD app Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, ionic2, angularfire2

OK BRAND new to Ionic development and I have following this basic tutorial https://javebratt.com/crud-ionic-firestore/. But in step #4 where you go to the detail page I am getting this error.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'detail/rXubsrpxkszX7GsaS96r'

This tutorial has been good but lots of gotchas in it with missing stuff and have been racking my brain and cant get past this gotcha. I am not even really sure what files are relevant in this error but here goes...

Here is my detail.page.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
  import { Note } from '../../models/note.interface';
  import { FirestoreService } from '../../services/data/firestore.service';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-detail',
    templateUrl: './detail.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./detail.page.scss'],
  })
  export class DetailPage implements OnInit {
    public note: Observable<Note>;
    constructor(
      private firestoreService: FirestoreService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      const noteId: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      this.note = this.firestoreService.getNoteDetail(noteId).valueChanges();
    }
  }
```

And here is the function I am using in firestore.service.ts

```
getNoteDetail(noteId: string): AngularFirestoreDocument<Note> {
  return this.firestore.collection('noteList').doc(noteId);
}
```

In app-routing.module.ts I see that it was called detail:id but everywhere else it is noteId so not sure that is correct but adding noteId didnt help.

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

  const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)},
    { path: 'create', loadChildren: './pages/create/create.module#CreatePageModule' },
    { path: 'detail:id', loadChildren: './pages/detail/detail.module#DetailPageModule' },
  ];

  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
  export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I have no idea where to chase this error down. Any help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

A few months late, but hopefully it will help out other people. So you are missing a path in your **app-routing.module.ts** file. In your `const routes: Routes = [ ...]`, add the following (it should look similar to this):

`{ path: 'detail/:id', loadChildren: './some path/detail.module#DetailPageModule' }`